# How do I chew bubble gum if I am wearing dental braces?

Tags: food, personal-care

As the title says, how can I chew gum if I am wearing braces. This is a big problem for me, because every time I chew a gum it  sticks in my braces and it is a real nightmare for me.

Sometimes I just chew the gum by putting it under my tongue and let the juice be tasted by my taste buds - honestly speaking this is not good!

And most of the time I just avoid it at any cost.

**Summary:**

[image][image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 7):

I would just not do it. It is not meant for you to do with metal braces. Doing so may damage your braces and make you have to wear them longer.

[askanorthodontist.com](http://askanorthodontist.com/braces/can-i-chew-gum-with-braces/):

> Chewing the sticky foods will bend the wire.  Chewing hard foods will
>   break the brackets, bands or the wire.  You need to remember, we
>   create a lot of pressure when we chew our food.
>
> Can I chew sugarless gum while I have braces?
>
> The answer is no.  A patient should not chew any type of gum while
>   braces are in place.  It does not matter what type of gum you are
>   using.  Gum bends the wire.

[dentalhealth.org](https://www.dentalhealth.org/tell-me-about/topic/orthodontics/living-with-my-brace):

> Is there anything I should avoid? Nail biting and chewing your pen or
>   pencil can damage or break your brace.

[Can you eat while wearing Invisalign® aligners? How about chewing gum?](http://www.animated-teeth.com/dental-braces/a-invisalign-braces-eating.htm)

> Eating with Invisalign, however, is not a good idea for a couple of
>   reasons (neither is chewing gum). In fact, having Invisalign®
>   treatment can be expected to have an effect on the way you eat, at
>   least to some degree. (Tips for relieving eating pain caused by
>   Invisalign® treatment.)
>
> Can you chew gum while wearing clear braces?
>
> You'll find that chewing gum with Invisalign® isn't a good idea. The
>   gum will tend to stick to the aligners' surface. It will be time
>   consuming and messy to remove.

---

**But if you are desperate:**

[How to get gum out of your braces?](http://www.ehow.com/how_5683476_gum-out-braces.html) So basically floss and brush, well.

[How to Avoid Foods That Will Damage Your Braces](http://www.wikihow.com/Avoid-Foods-That-Will-Damage-Your-Braces):

> Try to avoid too much sticky or doughy foods. These will get stuck in
>   your braces! While things like sliced bread will not necessarily break
>   any part of the braces, it can collect bacteria if not cleaned out
>   properly.

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, it is not good to chew gum if you are wearing braces. But still you like it. I am not sure, but before chewing gum you can lubricate your braces with some oil using your fingers or dipping a soft brush into the oil. This will prevent the gum from sticking to your braces.

Note of Caution: Try this with the oil that can be taken directly. Like olive oil (please confirm).

Answer (score 0):

I had braces for a ridiculous amount of time. Some gum is easier to chew with braces than other gum. It needs to be very cohesive, not necessarily more sugary which breaks apart. Small pieces of gum are better than bigger ones, and don't go pushing your gum up into your cheeks and stuff.

Just try to keep it off your dental work, but it may get stuck there eventually. Then you have to pick it out. Your orthodontist might not like it, but it could be worse.